# cmake bottlenecks on target linking despite -j option

Tags: multithreading, cmake, compilation, jobs, linkage

Suppose I have a CMake project with consists of two targets A and B, each of which comes with source files to be compiled.

If I build with -jN option (where N is a number of compile jobs, which I set to the number of logical cores on my machine), CMake will start building A by compiling *in parallel* all of its source files. Processor load is now maximum on my machine, if there are more files than logical cores.

Then it will link A, using a single core, and not starting anything else. This is a major bottleneck.

Only afterwards will it being building B by starting N parallel compilation jobs of N of B's sources (like for A). There is however absolutely no dependency of any of B on A. Or if there is, I can't tell and would like CMake to tell me that, which I guess constitutes the first half of my question.

Second, supposing that there is no dependency of B on A, could I tell CMake to begin building B as soon as possible, or indeed right at the start ?

Comment: "There is however absolutely no dependency of any of B on A. Or if there is, I can't tell and would like CMake to tell me that, which I guess constitutes the first half of my question." - Run `make B` and see whether `A` will be built or not. If `A` will be built, then `B` has a dependency (direct or indirect) from `A`. "I tell CMake to begin building B as soon as possible, or indeed right at the start?" - If you have some preferences in ordering, then just run `make` several times with corresponded parameters. Plain `make` is for the case when you have no preferences.

Comment: Sure, but that isn't a built-in CMake option. I'd have to write a CMakeLists that would specify to run a script that launches multiple `make` commands in parallel. Sounds very roundabout and unnatural and dirty.

Comment: Hmm, my previous description is probably not so good. I meant, that CMake (and other *build* tools like Make) are not please-build-things-in-that-order tools. As opposite, such build tools are used when there is no strict order between things, only **dependencies**. Taking these dependencies into the account, a build tool builds them in order which satisfies the dependencies. Such *dependency-based* build tools are not so good for preferences like "build B at the very beginning". That preference is better expressed in "normal" scripting languages like shell or python.

Comment: That makes complete sense, and I am expressing no preference as to build order *per se*. Simply to load up my processor and all of its cores with whatever (no preference as to order) is currently ready to go (has no dependencies or all dependencies finished).

Comment: `Ninja` seems to parallelize items better than `make`.

Comment: My research leads me there too. I also have a version of CMake that comes with Ninja which is also supposedly activated by default. Do you know how to double-check that though ?